# Tkinter widgets on incorrect Frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, tkinter

I'm trying to size entry boxes using pixels, so I am having to create a frame to get the correct size. I am also using a class to create tkinter Entry boxes so that I can put placeholders into the boxes. These both work separately; yet, when put together, the entry box refuses to go onto the correct frame even though I have specified the frame.

```py
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *

class GUI:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.usernameFrame = Frame(root, height=50, width=300, bg="GREEN", bd=3)
        self.usernameFrame.pack_propagate(0)
        self.usernameFrame.pack()

        self.usernameEntry = EntryPlaceholder(self.usernameFrame, "Username")
        self.usernameEntry.pack()


class EntryPlaceholder(Entry, object):

    def __init__(self, master=None, placeholder="placeholder"):
       super(EntryPlaceholder, self).__init__()

       self.placeholder = placeholder

       self.bind("<FocusIn>", self.clearText)
       self.bind("<FocusOut>", self.insertText)

       self.insertText()

    def insertText(self, *args):
        if self.get() == "":
            self.insert(0, self.placeholder)

    def clearText(self, *args):
        if self.get() == self.placeholder:
            self.delete(0, END)

root = tk.Tk()
gui = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The widget just gets placed onto the root frame.

Comment: _"I'm trying to size entry boxes using pixels"_ - out of curiosity, why? That usually leads to you having to do more work, and the UI not being very responsive to changes in screen size, resolution, font size, etc.

Comment: My GUI has been designed on Photoshop so I have just been looking at the location and size of the widgets on Photoshop in pixels and then placing them onto tkinter frames. Would you recommend doing this differently? Many thanks, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
def __init__(self, master=None, placeholder="placeholder"):
   super(EntryPlaceholder, self).__init__()
```

You aren't passing `master` on to the `__init__` of `EntryPlaceHolder`, so it's being put in the root window.

That code needs to be this:

```
def __init__(self, master=None, placeholder="placeholder"):
   super(EntryPlaceholder, self).__init__(master)
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly now. I don't quite understand, why does master need to be passed?

Comment: @Daniel: that tells the widget where it goes. If you don't tell it what frame (or other widget) is its master, it goes in the root window.